# My profile is showing a recent post that isn't mine

Tags: support, recent-activity, voting

I'm looking at my profile.  One thread shows one post with a -1 and one with a +4.  The +4 post is really mine, the -1 is someone else's that I downvoted and commented on.  This doesn't seem right.  It does show the -1 point for downvoting--it's like it's really displaying rep activity rather than posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it's like it's really displaying rep
>   activity rather than posts

That's exactly what it **is** doing. It's displaying your rep changes. You lost 1 rep for downvoting a question, that's a rep change, thus it's displayed. Don't stress, nobody can see that page except for you. And diamond mods. They can however see your public profile ([see mine for an example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131874/farseeker))

Comment: To clarify, your profile *is* public, but you're not looking at your profile, you're looking at your recent activity page (the envelope icon at the top). Your profile does actually show your posts

Comment: For completeness, the recent activity page is visible to the currently logged in user and diamond mods.

Comment: @Jon Well, most cases of "nobody can see/do that but you" are actually "nobody can see/do that but you and diamond mods", but yes :)

Comment: In the spirit of completeness I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Michael: Yeah. In this case, though, IIRC 10k users used to be able to see people's recent activity pages and that caused... problems... so they restricted it further.

Comment: @Jon Oh. Yeah, that does seem not good; I wasn't around for that :)

Comment: Then the wording should be changed to what it's really showing.